# How can I install Pyomo bilevel package?

Tags: pyomo

I am trying-

from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.bilevel import *

but unable to run as it shows an error:- No module named 'pyomo.bilevel'. How can I import Pyomo.bilevel?

Comment: Hi Samarth, have you installed the pyomo package? For example `pip install pyomo`?

Comment: Which version of pyomo are you using? Since `Pyomo 5.7.3` (I think) all the bilevel approach of `pyomo` was moved to [PAO](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) — Python-based package for Adversarial Optimization. then, you need to try `pip install pao` and work with that

Comment: I have installed Pyomo and Pao. It is not showing an error when I am importing Pao for the submodel. Thanks.